# How to make multiple connections with Talend Job?

Tags: talend

I am writing a talend job to replicate mysql database from client to server
I am using "tmysqlconnection" and tmysql_row" component
now the difficulty here is I am passing context params to my job like

```
USE "+context.destination_database+";

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;



SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('main.', column_name)) 
    INTO @fields_name
    FROM  information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name='"+context.mysql_source_table+"';

SELECT @fields_name;


SELECT id FROM "+context.mysql_source_database+"."+context.mysql_source_table_mac+" order by id asc limit 2,1  INTO @mac_id;

SELECT @mac_id;
```

its a small portion of myquery in which destination database in my servers database located on some other machine and source database is clients machine
the real problem came here because my talend job use the specific database ie client or server to find both databases which results in to job failure
how can i connect to both of my  mysql databases  and use the context params in my query so that my job knows that from which database i can expect data

Answer (score 1):

Use the tMySqlrow to select from your source database, and create another component, tMysqlOutput to create the table in your new database.